# After making an AJAX call using fetch(), how do I append a P tag in an HTML list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, fetch-api, innerhtml

I am new and not afraid of working on a problem and I'm grateful for all the knowledge available. But I have tried and failed for too long now.

```js
// 1. GET request using fetch()
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
  // Convert received data to JSON
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(users => show(users));

  function show(users) {
    const para = document.querySelector("p");
    for (let user of users) {
      let html = `<p>${user.title}</p>`;
        para.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", html);
    }
  };
```

```html
 <ul> <!-- loop start -->
    <li>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
      <p></p> <!-- append to <p>${users.title}</p> for each obj -->
    </li>
  </ul> <!-- loop end -->
```

Of course that will loop the P tag with `user.title` for each json object. But that's as far as I get... lots of successful variations though building a new list.

I keep going back to thinking I'm close with something like:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p'))
  .forEach(p => {
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML
    .replace();
})
```

But I just am not sure and cant get it even close enough to know I may be on the right track. I know the `replace()` method isn't right, and 'replaceWith()' is Jquery... is this where the show function woudl run?  I keep coming back to this as I did something similar in a tutorial and it seems frustratingly close.

I'm not asking anyone to do it for me 'cause then I won't learn but even a hint would be inspiring enough to drive me to invest countless more hours. Still, beats the other sh!t I could be doing at my age, like sleeping. Cheers ~

Comment: Could you clarify what the expected result is?

Comment: You're inserting `afterend`, resulting in the items being inserted in reverse order after everything is done, but other than that, I don't understand what exactly the problem is, your code is successfully fetching and inserting each todo title

Comment: Result sent to DOM:

<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="xxx" />
    <p>${user.title}</p>
  </li>
</ul>

repeated for each {user.title} object - hmmm, not sure how to use markdown in comments. sry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to make `<li>` elements to add to the unordered list with [`Element#append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(users => show(users));

function show(users) {
  const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  for (const user of users) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = user.title;
    li.append(p);
    ul.append(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

##### You can use the `template` element to create a template of the entire html snippet you want in your loop.

Then, in your loop, create a clone of that template, update the parts you want to update, and append to the ul element.

```js
// 1. GET request using fetch()
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
  // Convert received data to JSON
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(users => show(users));

function show(users) {
  // get target list
  const list = document.querySelector('ul');
  for (let user of users) {
    // clone your template
    const templateClone = document.querySelector('#listItemTemplate').content.cloneNode(true);
    // insert user title into paragraph element of cloned template
    templateClone.querySelector('p').innerText = user.title;
    // append to end of the list
    list.appendChild(templateClone);
  }
};
```

```html
<ul>
</ul>


<template id="listItemTemplate">
   <li>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
      <p></p>
    </li>
 </template>
```